# Ansible update still shows old version

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I upgraded ansible from version 2.0 to 2.3.1 on a Debian 8 server and followed the instructions that Ansible provided:

1. Add to Sources list:
   `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main`
2. Run Following Commands:

   `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ansible`

I checked `which ansible`, shows to be pointed to /usr/local/bin.
When I ran echo $PATH, I see that /usr/local/bin is listed. Do i need to run an extra step to get the correct version of Ansible?

I dont have the output present. But when I ran apt, it updated successfully to ansible 2.3.1

UPDATE: ansible was originally installed via pip. When I run `pip install --upgrade ansible, I get:

```
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-jyjjV6/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
Downloading/unpacking pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading PyNaCl-1.1.2.tar.gz (3.1MB): 3.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-jyjjV6/pynacl/setup.py) egg_info for package pynacl
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-jyjjV6/pynacl/setup.py", line 232, in <module>
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 312, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1091, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1103, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 379, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 639, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 669, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 852, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1080, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1068, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory

 #include <ffi.h>

                 ^

compilation terminated.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-jyjjV6/pynacl/setup.py", line 232, in <module>

    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 312, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve

    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1091, in best_match

    return self.obtain(req, installer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1103, in obtain

    return installer(requirement)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 379, in fetch_build_egg

    return cmd.easy_install(req)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 639, in easy_install

    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 669, in install_item

    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 852, in install_eggs

    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1080, in build_and_install

    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1068, in run_setup

    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jyjjV6/pynacl
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

When I tried running apt-get install and running /usr/bin/ansible --version, I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 46, in <module>
    from ansible.module_utils._text import to_text
ImportError: No module named _text
```

Ideally, I would like to upgrade via pip, but I can't seem to get it to run. I will settle to using apt-get though.

Comment: What was the output of the install command?

Comment: What is `pip list | grep ansible` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DEB package install ansible in `/usr/bin/ansible`, I guess your previous install wasn't from a DEB package (but `pip` instead?) and it explains why you have 2 versions of ansible.
Depending the definition of your `PATH`, your not getting the new version.

You should clean the previous install (`pip uninstall`?)

UPDATE: the `pip install --upgrade` is failing because it's trying to build some C bindings of ansible dependencies.

You should uninstall the version installed with `pip`, then reinstall the DEB package:

```
pip uninstall --yes ansible
apt install --yes --reinstall ansible
```

Mixing installation from system package and pip is never a good idea...

Comment: I do see /usr/bin/ansible present but when I run /usr/bin/ansible --version I get a stacktrace. I had to use apt-get, because pip was failing to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: I guess that's because you have 2 version of the ansible libs in python. But providing the stacktrace would be a good help!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case `pip list | grep <package name>` showed the new version, but the global package inside `\usr\bin` (which was probably installed by rpm), remained as the old version. Usually you can check global package version with `<package name> --version`.

To fix it I had to upgrade with sudo: `sudo pip install -U <package name>`

Or if inside [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io), install without sudo, but with -I to ignore the global packages:

`pip install -I <package name>`